# Как проверить идет ли закачка файла с сайта при помощи PHP?

Tags: php

Ситуация такая, есть ссылка, при переходе на которую начинается автозагрузка.
Как при помощи php проверить пойдет ли загрузка по ссылке?
Т.е есть 2 ссылки, одна рабочая, вторая тоже но загрузка файла не начинается, как при помощи php их отсортировать

Comment: Скорее всего по заголовкам...

Comment: Ну если это Ваш сайт проверяйте не ссылку, а проверяйте присутствие файла